# XMPP SASL authenfication

Tags: xmpp

I want to implement a simple authentication in C++. For now I can initiate a stream, get supported mechanisms and chose one. It works fine, but now I can't read out (from http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0034.html#sect-id259287 ) what I have to write into the plaintext handshake. Decoding the string I get "robsecret". So how do I do it with username "user" and passsword "pass"?
PS: Response using "userpass" is "".
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do of course realize that this is a retracted XEP you are trying to find information in?
The relevant documents are [RFC 6120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120) (XMPP Core) and [RFC 4616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616) (SASL PLAIN).
Short version:
PLAIN requires you to send base64("authzid\0authcid\0password"), where authzid is usually empty and authcid is your username.

Comment: Thank you very much. And thanks for the RFCs. I will use them for more information.